# Values not getting in the drop down box in vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am getting values from the DB to the page where the dropdown box is there but the dropdown box not returning the value. The code as shown below,

### Script

```
methods: {
        editState(id){
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token'); 
              axios.get(baseUrl+'/state/edit/'+id)
              .then((response) => {

                    alert(response.data[0].form.country_name);

                    this.form = response.data[0].form;

                     setTimeout(() => {
                         this.subComponentLoading = true;
                    }, 500);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
       }
```

### Vue

```
<d-field-group class="field-group field-row" label-for = "country_name" label="Country Name" label-class="col-4">
    <d-select :options="Countries" v-model="form.country_id" id="country_id" name = "country_name"  wrapper-class="col-7">

    </d-select>
</d-field-group>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please explain further what _"the dropdown box not returning the value"_ means? What do you expect to see vs what you're actually seeing?

Comment: I can't see anything in the dropdown box. But the correct value showing in the alert but it is not display in the dropdown box

Comment: I need to show country name and zone name in the boxes

Comment: This is probably dependent on what your initial `data` looks like for `form`. Please show that

Comment: I am not getting what you want?

Comment: Your component's `data() { ... }` function, please. If not a component, then the `data: { ... }`

Comment: data () {
   return {
    isStateEditVisible: false,
    form :{
     state_name: '',
     isStateEnabled: true,
     ISO_Code: '',
     country_name: '',
     zone_name: '',
     Countries: [],
     Zones: [],
    }
   }
  }

Comment: I am getting values from DB and now i want to apply them to those dropbox, options also am getting but not showing on dropdown to edit

Comment: So assign them to `this.Countries`. Why is `Countries` in the `form` object? Also, since you're attempting to bind `v-model="form.country_id"`, you should add an initial `country_id` property to `form` in your `data()` function

Comment: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token');
   axios.get(baseUrl+'/country/fetch')
   .then((response) => {
    this.Countries = response.data;
   });
   
   axios.get(baseUrl+'/zone/fetch')
   .then((response) => {
    this.Zones = response.data;
   });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183603/discussion-between-kevin-and-phil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that I see are wrong...

1. `Countries` is inside the `form` object but you don't assign or read it from there. Move it to the top level
2. You are binding a `v-model` to `form.country_id` but this does not initially exist. Add it to the `form` object.

To summarise...

```js
data () {
  return {
    isStateEditVisible: false, 
    form: {
      state_name: '', 
      isStateEnabled: true, 
      ISO_Code: '', 
      country_id: '', //  added this
      country_name: '', 
      zone_name: ''
    },
    Countries: [],    //  moved this
    Zones: []         //  and this
  }
}
```

In order to react to data changes, Vue needs to know about them up-front. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html